# Usar Procedimientos de MySQL en GeneXus

Tags: mysql, genexus, genexus15

¿Es posible invocar procedimientos creados en MySQL desde Genexus?.
De ser así, ¿cómo puedo hacerlo? ¿existe alguna guía?

Answer (score 2):

Si lo que quieres es poder llamar Store Procedures (SP) con codigo GeneXus, esto lo podes hacer de la siguiente forma:

1) A nivel de las propiedades del modelo tienes una propiedad llamada LIST OF REMOTE PROGRAMS (ODBC/JDBC) aquí colocas el nombre de los SP separados por espacio, si es que tienes mas de uno. (en Gx 90 esta propiedad esta a nivel del DBMS)

2) Desde el objeto que necesitas llamar al SP simplemente haces un call clasico de GeneXus

Ej: Supongamos que tu SP se llama ProcedureTest

haces: 
        call('ProcedureTest', &parm1, &parm2, ......)

Para mayor información puedes recurrir a las siguientes URL de apoyo para temas relacionados a genexus:

http://search.genexus.com/

https://wiki.genexus.com/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rsfP3ZA7AD0

https://www.youtube.com/user/GXMarketing/playlists

Saludos, espero te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Hola, tengo que ejecutar un procedimiento almacenado en  Genexus 8, y esta claro como se logra esto, pero sabes tu como se hace para poder reibir la informacion de un SP que retorna una tabla? al hacer el call, le debo pasar algun tipo especial de parametro de salida para que me devuelva los datos, como por ejemplo en un  SDT?. Agradezco tus comentarios al respecto. Saludos

Comment: lo que se me ocurre para resolver lo que me dices es que en tu store procedure hagas uso de una vista y posteriormente leas esa tabla generada con un foreach y puede que un sdt que se base en las columns de la view o tabla. de esa manera tendrias en tu sdt cargada la estructura que requieres. en la sig. url tienes un ejemplo de como crear una view en mysql: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/create-sql-views-mysql.aspx

Comment: lamentablemente no tengo opcion de modificar el SP, ya que es codigo en el cliente. por eso pense que podria pasar los resultadpos devueltos a traces de alguna variable